# How to declare click function inside If statement?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, click

I know there is a small mistake in the if statement closing.

Can anyone show me, how to declare click function inside the If statement?

```
if (($("#target").click(function () {
    $("#thediv").scrollTop = $("#thediv").scrollHeight;
});
})
else {
    $("#thediv2").scrollTop = $("#thediv").scrollHeight;

}
```

Comment: Can you explain your goal ?

Comment: Unable to get the motive???

Comment: `.click` doesn't return any Boolean you can't do that

Comment: I formatted your code intendations for readability and it became appearent your closing braces aren't matching. I wasn't sure if that was a copy-paste error or your actual code so I left them in. If that is your actual code you need to replace the `}); }) else` with just `} else`.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind it to

```
$('document').on('click',function(event){
 if(event.target.id == 'target'){ ... }
 else {}
...
})
```